# Animate a procedural sea in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures, procedural

I'm working on my first project with Three.js and I'm hitting against a wall right now.

I would like to know what would be the best way to make an animated (low-poly) sea inside Three.js , I've been trying since yesterday with displacementMaps but I have been reading that displacementMaps can't be animated ? (is that true ?)

```
var faceGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(200,200,subdivisions,subdivisions);
var faceMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xeeeeee, side: THREE.DoubleSide,transparent: true,opacity: .3,specular: 0x333333,shading: THREE.FlatShading})
var face1 = new THREE.Mesh(faceGeo,faceMat);

face1.rotation.x = -(Math.PI /2);
face1.position.y = -30
face1.position.z = -90

textureDiff.load("_textures/dispmap_sea.png",function(image){
  image.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  image.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  image.repeat = new THREE.Vector2(1,1);
  image.anisotropy = renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();

  face1.material.displacementMap = image;
  face1.material.displacementScale = 10;
});
```

in update

```
displacementPos++;

face1.material.displacementMap.offset = new THREE.Vector2(displacementPos,displacementPos);

face1.material.needsUpdate = true;
face1.material.displacementMap.needsUpdate = true;
```

It would be the easiest way but if it is impossible, I don't know what my other options are.

Thank you for your help.
A Three.js amateur and enthusiast.

Comment: Try to see something about the Perlin Noise. While it's used for procedural terrain generation, with some tuning it can generate fantastic low poly waves

Answer (score 2):

There are some great examples of shaders for water (in this case called ocean) on [the Three.js examples page](http://threejs.org/examples/):

- http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_shaders_ocean
- http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_shaders_ocean2

Another good starting point is [this dedicated **ocean - Realistic water shader for Three.js** github page](https://github.com/jbouny/ocean#ocean---realistic-water-shader-for-threejs).

Comment: Those are good examples but they are not what I want to accomplish. I want the vertices of the plane to move like an ocean , but it's all very low poly and shouldn't look realistic at all. ( also I don't understand how to build those custom shaders , I'm truly a beginner in Three.js ) But thanks for the answer anyway.